# change state by click into the text?

Tags: vue.js

I need to create a select option to switch to notify/not notify status. But my customer wants to use the regular text format. The default value is notify, when clicking on the text will change to no notify. I am having trouble in this case. I'm trying to make it with checkbox and label like this but if I click on one, they all change state. How best to handle this case? This my code of this problem and the picture about it. The initial value of selected_option is like this `private selected_option: any = 'no notify'`

```
<div class="d-block">
          <ul class="list-unstyled m-0">
            <li
              v-for="group in list_groups"
              :key="group.id"
              class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3"
            >
              <input
                class="form-check-input w--4 h--4 rounded-0 m-0 me-6"
                type="checkbox"
                :value="group.id"
                :id="group.id"
              />
              <div class="w--11 h--11 me-3">
                <img
                  :src="group.avatar"
                  alt="group-avatar"
                  class="img-cover w-100"
                />
              </div>
              <label :for="group.id" class="form-check-label">
                {{ group.name }}
              </label>
              <div class="ms-auto">
                    <input
                      @change="changeNotifyOption"
                      type="checkbox"
                      class=""
                      :id="`notify${group.id}`"
                      v-model="selected_option"
                      true-value="notify"
                      false-value="no notify"
                    />
                    <label
                      class="text-primary cursor-pointer"
                      :for="`notify${group.id}`"
                      >{{ selected_option }}</label
                    >
                  </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

[image]   [image]

Comment: are you using `v-for`?

Comment: yes, I need to use v-for above to get all groups of the current user.

Comment: We need the complete code so we can help you, there's at least one `v-for` missing.

Comment: please share its code and the code the method `changeNotifyOption`

Comment: `<label><input ..... /><span class="text-primary">.....</span></label>` is all you need

Comment: @MikelGranero I just update my description. The method `changeNotifyOption` doesn't have anything, I just want to `console.log(selected_option)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can I show me how it works?

Comment: please share the code of `changeNotifyOption` method

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The method `changeNotifyOption` doesn't have anything, I just want to `console.log(selected_option)`. I don't do anything with the method

Comment: and how is `selected_option` defined?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I define the initial value of `selected_option` as `no-notify`. You can see this in my description.  Now my problem is that when I click into a checkbox, all will change state. I just want to fix that

Comment: Can you guys give me some ways to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `selected_option` property into `group` object like:

```
list_groups: [{id: 1, selected_option: null}, {id: 2, selected_option: null}]
```

then change `v-model` as `v-model="group.selected_option"` and `{{ selected_option }}` as `{{ group.selected_option || selected_option }}`